# How combine two versioned transactions?

Tags: web3.js, transactions, versionedtransactions

I receive swap VersionedTransaction from https://quote-api.jup.ag/v3/swap.
I want to add some instructions to this transaction.
I create addition VersionedTransaction with my instructions but not found way to combine my transaction and transaction that I receive?

How combine VersionedTransactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jupiter [added a section to their docs](https://docs.jup.ag/integrating-jupiter/composing-with-versioned-transactions) on how you can add your instructions to a `VersionedTransaction`.

Comment: update: link is now at https://docs.jup.ag/docs/additional-topics/composing-with-versioned-transaction